# How to do auto update from JSON on app screen? SwiftUI

Tags: json, url, swiftui, auto-update

I`m new at swift,
The data in JSON will be updated for example every 15 seconds. How to correctly update them on the application screen?

In Android studio I used a handler, maybe there is something similar and that the function or output needs to be updated?

```
import SwiftUI

struct DATA: Codable {
    let ONE_R: Float
    let TWO_R: Float
}

struct AllTEC: View {
    @State var user: DATA?
    var body: some View {
        Text("ONE: \(user?.ONE_R ?? 0)")  \\correct for string incorrect for float
            .onAppear(perform: loadD)
    }
}

extension AllTEC
{
    func loadD() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://symbiosys-a415a.firebaseio.com/DATA.json")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
              print("error: \(error!)")
              return
        }
        guard let data = data else{
              print("no data")
              return
        }
        guard let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(DATA.self, from: data) else {
        print("Error: Couldn't decode data ito user")
        return
        }
        print("gotten user is \(user.ONE_R)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.user = user
    }
    task.resume()
   }
}

struct AllTEC_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
          AllTEC()
    }
}
```

JSON

```
{
"ONE_R":98.4,
"TWO_R":27.7
}
```

Comment: Every time you change `user`, the view should automatically update.

Comment: @koen can you show some example if this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you, it shows how to use a `Timer` to schedule yor requests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701410/refresh-json-data-after-a-few-seconds-in-swift